# AAM Instruction in EMU8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

What is the mechanism of `AAM` instruction in assembly language?
Suppose:

```
MOV AL,35H
MOV BL,33H
MUL BL
AAM
```

Here how `AAM` works?

Comment: Which part of [the documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/AAM.html) do you not understand?

Comment: after multiplication

Comment: The values you multiplied are not unpacked BCD values. Unpacked BCD values are between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> MOV AL,35H   ; This is 53 in decimal
> MOV BL,33H   ; This is 51 in decimal
> MUL BL
> AAM
> ```

The `AAM` instruction divides the `AL` register by 10, leaving the quotient in `AH` and the remainder in `AL`.

Since `AAM` solely depends on the value in `AL`, you need to work out its value first.

Given that `AL = 53` and `BL = 51`, `MUL BL` (which multiplies them) leaves 53 * 51 = 2703 in `AX`.
This translates to `AH = 10` and `AL = 143` because `AX = AH * 256 + AL`.

Applying `AAM` then produces `AH = 143 \ 10 = 14` and `AL = 143 % 10 = 3`.

*Although designed that way, the use of the `AAM` instruction is not limited to unpacked BCD. You can use it as a general division by 10 instruction! With the dividend in `AL` only of course.*